# ASP.NET Core Web API does not show error 500 in production

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I delete a record in development mode, it returns an error 500 (expected error), but when it is published on the server it returns the following message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apijinetes.server.com/api/cuponeras/1' from origin 'https://jinetes.otroserver.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> polyfills.5835973a74f5b04ed1da.js:1 DELETE https://apijinetes.server.com/api/cuponeras/1 net::ERR_FAILED

It doesn't return a http 500 error.

Although it seems that the error is from CORS, I have it enabled in the startup file in the `ConfigureServices` and in `Configure` methods:

```
services.AddCors(options=> {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://jinetes.server.com","http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider ServiceProvider)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
      
       app.UseHttpsRedirection();
       app.UseRouting();
       app.UseCors();  // <------
       app.UseAuthentication();
       app.UseAuthorization();
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

I handle this error from the frontend with Angular and if it is a 500 I show a message, but in this case I can't show anything because it returns this error -> net :: ERR_FAILED

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23759) be the case for you?

Comment: Also can you try using any REST client (Postman/Insomnia) and try that request and see if there is CORS header? For browser it wouldn't work because browser would stop the request if OPTIONS request does not have CORS header.

Comment: Using Postman it gives me a 500 status error, which is expected, but not when I use the API from the frontend with angular, I get the CORS error, and actually the 500 error is generated because it cannot and should not delete the that record Sql Server therefore generates a 500 that does not show it to me. I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Yes I know it's expected, can you check the Postman response headers, see if there is CORS header returned? if not there is something wrong with your CORS config. How about other responses/APIs, do they have CORS headers?

Answer (score 0):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://apijinetes.server.com/api/cuponeras/1' from origin 'https://jinetes.otroserver.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In your code, we can find that the allowed origins you set are `'https://jinetes.server.com'` and `'http://localhost:4200'`, but you make request from `'https://jinetes.otroserver.com'`, which seems cause this issue.

You can try to modify the code to add it to default policy, like below.

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://jinetes.server.com", "http://localhost:4200", "https://jinetes.otroserver.com")
```